# Android response code 200 from php mysql but does not make entries in database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am sending data from my android app form to php mysql server and from server i am getting response code 200 but failed to make any entries into database.

**Here is my php file where i am sending POST variables**

```
    <?php

$host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pass='pass';
$db='App';


$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pass,$db);


$First_Name=$_POST['First_Name'];
$Last_Name=$_POST['Last_Name'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Mail_ID=$_POST['Mail_ID'];
$Password =$_POST['Password'];
$La=$_POST['La'];
$Lo=$_POST['Lo'];
$Ac=$_POST['Ac'];
$Pro=$_POST['Pro'];

if($con){
 echo "Connected Successfully to database $First_Name "; //Print Variable to Check that file is getting inputs.Its Working.
}
else{
echo 'Failed To Connect to database ';
}


$sql="INSERT INTO `mobile_App`(`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Phone`, `Mail_ID`, `Password`, `La`, `Lo`, `Ac`, `Pro`)
VALUES ($First_Name,$Last_Name,$Phone,$Mail_ID,$Password,$La,$Lo,$Ac,$Pro)";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo 'Data Inserted Successfully';
}
else{
echo "ERROR: could not able to execute $sql.".
mysqli_error($con) ;
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**This is my Java File**

```
    public class Sending_Data_To_Server extends AsyncTask{
String Lo,La,Ac,Pro,First_Name,Last_Name,Phone,Mail_ID,Password;
BufferedReader reader;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //Variables
    First_Name=params[0];
    Last_Name=params[1];
    Phone=params[2];
    Mail_ID=params[3];
    Password=params[4];
    Lo=params[5];
    La=params[6];
    Ac=params[7];
    Pro=params[8];
    Log.d("SEND DATA VALUES",First_Name+Last_Name+Lo+La+Phone);


    try {
        String data= URLEncoder.encode("First_Name","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(First_Name,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" +URLEncoder.encode("Last_Name","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Last_Name,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Phone","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Phone,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Mail_ID","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Mail_ID,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Password","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Password,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("La","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(La,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Lo","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Lo,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Ac","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Ac,"UTF-8");
        data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Pro","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Pro,"UTF-8");



        URL url=new URL("test/Android/Data/data.php");   // can't post complete url due to restriction to new users 
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //For POST Only - Begin
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os=connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        connection.connect();
        //For POST Only End
        int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Sending Class----","POST RESPONSE CODE "+responseCode);

        if (responseCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            //Success
            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();

            while((inputLine=reader.readLine())!=null){
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            reader.close();

            //Print Result
            Log.d("SENDING CLASS----",response.toString());

        }
        else{
            Log.d("SENDING CLASS---","POST did not work");

        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "DATA SUBMITTED";
}

}
```

**Here is Logcat**

```
    06-29 20:48:52.703 7211-7211/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/REGISTRATION CLASS: ----ALL DATA READY AND CAPTURED
06-29 20:48:52.723 7211-29559/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/SEND DATA VALUES: helloworld28.531212977.25688999865321472
06-29 20:48:52.893 7211-7211/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for AppIntroFragment{423d9470 #1 id=0x7f0e009f android:switcher:2131624095:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
06-29 20:48:52.933 7211-7211/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/AppIntroBaseFragment: Slide Hello World has been selected.
06-29 20:48:53.423 7211-29559/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/Sending Class----: POST RESPONSE CODE 200
06-29 20:48:53.423 7211-29559/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/SENDING CLASS----: Connected Successfully to database hello ERROR: could not able to execute INSERT INTO `mobile_App`(`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Phone`, `Mail_ID`, `Password`, `La`, `Lo`, `Ac`, `Pro`)VALUES (hello,world,9810012345,Google@gmail.com,adffgghhjjk,77.2568899,28.5312129,37.5,Fixed).You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,adffgghhjjk,77.2568899,28.5312129,37.5,fused)' at line 2
```

And my Database structure 
[Rows Where I want to insert app data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQTvy.png)

Till now i have tried so many tutorials and guide and most of the places i have seen HttpClient which is depreciated so i am working with only HttpUrlConnection and as server returned status code 200 i think its some fault in php mysql file but not sure.

As @Adam Forbis suggest to print mysql error and check that value is getting by php file.So i did and i edit my PHP file to get those details and now i m updating logcat with mysql error

Comment: put up the code where you are inserting to database ?

Comment: its in php file above and i m retrieving  POST variable from java class above

Comment: Try using msqli_error() : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to get your error, it definitely seems to be a server side issue.

Comment: @AdamForbis sorry but i am not good in php still i tried to use mysqli_error like this if(!mysqli_query($con,"SET a=1")){
printf("Failed: ",mysqli_error($con)); 
}
but its only throws Failed String as i mention in printf

Comment: have you made sure that the data you are sending up has actually made it to the script?

Comment: @AdamForbis Yes I just checked by adding First_Name variable into echo and its prints as i filled in form

Comment: Answer by @DOCbrink seems to be the best one so far, but some more advice would be to use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try as follow in you're php file (replace you're $sql var by this one):

```
$sql="
    INSERT INTO `mobile_App`
    (
        `First_Name`,
        `Last_Name`,
        `Phone`,
        `Mail_ID`,
        `Password`,
        `La`,
        `Lo`,
        `Ac`,
        `Pro`
    )
    VALUES (
        '".$First_Name."',
        '".$Last_Name."',
        $Phone,
        '".$Mail_ID."',
        '".$Password."',
        $La,
        $Lo,
        $Ac,
        '".$Pro."'
    )
;";
```

This is also the same answer at f_anto, but i confirm that you must have the single quote arround you're strings. 
(i only prefere write '".$var."' at '$var')

this work perfectly for me (similar code) for testing you're problem :

```
<?php


$db = mysqli_connect("host", "userLogin", "userPwd", "dbName");

$id = 999;
$idc = 1;
$idd = 0;
$p = "gpog@email.com";
$la = 15478.12;
$l = 0;

$sql="
        INSERT INTO `table`
        (
            `field1`,
            `field2`,
            `field3`,
            `field4`,
            `field5`,
            `field6`
        )
        VALUES (
            $id,
            $idc,
            $idd,
            '".$p."',
            $la,
            $l
        )
    ;";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);

var_dump(mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: i also recommand to use ExecutorService instead of AsynchTask

Comment: Thankyou so much its working fine and as i tried to enter phone number it was showing 2147483647 instead of phone number so i changed phone number INT into varchar now its taking phone number as i entered

Comment: You're welcome :) if you phone number displayed 2147483647,it's because you're working on a 32 bit computer,and this is the max value for an int (i think) so if you try to store bigger it will take this value. Change to varchar is better yes :) On 64 system you can store bigger numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

For the value of inserting query you should make like this (add quote in each value)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mobile_App(First_Name,Last_Name,Phone,Mail_ID,Password,La,Lo,Ac,Pro)
VALUES ('$First_Name','$Last_Name','$Phone','$Mail_ID','$Password','$La','$Lo','$Ac','$Pro')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Async task instead to call php api.

```
public static class backgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //do something before putting values in database 
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        //call php api here with the arguments

        String url = "YOUR_PHP_API_URL_WITH_ARGUMENTS";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return f_url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] f_url) {
        //do something after putting values in database
    }
}
```

Also, make changes in your php api. Make it like this. I removed single quotes.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO mobile_App(First_Name,Last_Name,Phone,Mail_ID,Password,La,Lo,Ac,Pro)
VALUES ($First_Name,$Last_Name,$Phone,$Mail_ID,$Password,$La,$Lo,$Ac,$Pro)";
```

Comment: I am using HttpUrlconnection and Httpclient is depreciated that;s why i am not using this.I want to insert via HttpUrlConnection. I also tried both case in php file with single quotes and without quotes like you mention but still not working

Comment: Have you tries using volley library?

Comment: Yes i tried using volley but my basic point is to avoid adding additional library into app Volley is really easy to use and work well too

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023533/how-can-i-call-a-php-script-from-java-code

Comment: what unique about it its just calling php from java file i am not good in handling sql things so that's why i had this problem